# How can I subscribe to a single event using Polkadot.js API?

Tags: substrate, polkadot, polkadot-js

I want to subscribe to a single event (or a list of events) using the Polkadot.js API. However, I have only found information on how to [traverse events](https://polkadot.js.org/docs/api/examples/promise/system-events) and then filter the results. In addition, the [documentation about events](https://polkadot.js.org/docs/substrate/events) lists all the events emitted, but I haven't found a way to subscribe to a single one.

Is this possible? How could I do that? Thanks!

Comment: Short update. The [documentation](https://polkadot.js.org/docs/api/start/basics#metadata) says `...metadata also provides information on events, these are query-able via the api.query.system.events()`, therefore, I don't think it is possible to subscribe to a single event. From what I understood, the event metadata, for exemple `api.events.gilt.BidPlaced.is`, can be used on the `EventRecord` from the `Vec<EventRecord>` returned from the `api.query.system.events()` to check whether the event is of that specific kind, like `api.events.gilt.BidPlaced.is(<EventRecord>)`.